# Finding inverse of matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Find the inverse of the following matrix$$\begin{pmatrix}ab&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ I found $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{ab}&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ but one of my friend got $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{a}&0\\0&\frac{1}{b}\end{pmatrix}$$ then which is the correct answer.

Comment: You need to solve $\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} ab & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.  That's four (simple, small) equations and 4 variables: w, x, y, z.

Comment: Neither is correct. The inverse of a diagonal matrix is the diagonal matrix of the inverses.

Comment: Certainly your friend's answer has no right to be correct, because it would imply that $\begin{pmatrix} 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has _different inverses_ depending on whether you consider it to be $\begin{pmatrix} 2\cdot 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix} 3\cdot 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: yes now I edited another answer that I got now , is it the right one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To determine which is correct, try to multiply them
$$
\pmatrix{ab & 0 \\ 0 & 1}\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/(ab)} = \pmatrix{ab & 0 \\ 0 & 1/(ab)}.
$$
Since this is not the identity matrix, you have not found the correct inverse. If you do the same thing for the other suggestion, you also find that this isn't the correct inverse.

Maybe you could try a certain matrix of the form
$$
\pmatrix{? & 0 \\ 0 & 1}.
$$

Comment: I got another answer and I put it in place of previous answer , is it correct?

Comment: @mahavir: That looks right. Good job.

Answer (score 6):

Just to make a good point easy for memorizing:

$$\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\pmatrix{d & -b \\ -c & a}.$$ where $ad-bc\neq0$.

Comment: But it would be much more instructive to prove that formula (and funnier :) )

Comment: @chubakueno: Yes you're right. I didn't do that because the way which Thomas pointed is much more better than mine. Indeed, he gives us the points behind the solution. I just noted a common formula. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the matrix above. Solve $Ax=y$. This gives $x_1 = {1 \over ab}y_1, x_2 = y_2$. Now write the map $y \mapsto ({1 \over ab}y_1, y_2)$ as a matrix, this is the inverse.